# Ubuntu 18.04 takes a lot of time to start & resume file missing

Tags: 18.04, resume

I have done a fresh install on a DELL i7 8550U with Ubuntu 18.04. 2 LTS.

My problem is that it takes quite a lot time to start although I do not launch any applications while starting up.

I have tried the following as suggested in relevant topics here:

1. `sudo gedit /etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/networking.service`  and put TimeOutStart from 5min to 5sec
2. `sudo gedit /etc/systemd/system.conf` and put

   ```
   DefaultTimeoutStartSec=3s
   DefaultTimeoutStopSec=3s
   ```

But nothing happened. Finally I have tried to open the resume file to set NO RESUME at `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d` but it does not exist!

Any idea on that?

Comment: Use the command `dmesg` that will sow the startup sequence and where you can see if there is something wrong. It could also be helpfull if you posted the output from `dmesg`  in your question.

Comment: The `resume` file probably doesn't exist because you've defined your swap as `/swapfile` in `/etc/fstab`. How long is a "long startup time"?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no /etc/fstab file in my computer. the output of dmesg is quite long to post here.... Any idea how to post it? The mean time of startup is :systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 6.295s (firmware) + 11.596s (loader) + 2.959s (kernel) + 8.328s (userspace) = 29.180s
graphical.target reached after 8.307s in userspace

Comment: I think that it is a long starup time comparing with the startup time that I had when I was using only  windows 10